# The closure of $\{z:|f(z)|<c\}$is the set $\{z:|f(z)|\leq c\}$ using map theorem

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, entire-functions

Working with complex numbers, let $f$ be an entire and non-constant function.

What I want to show is that for any positive real number c>0, the closure of $\{z:|f(z)|<c\} = \{z:|f(z)|≤c\}$.
I've managed to show the inclusion going from left to right using balls argument. However, I'm struggling with the other inclusion.

I've found a previous discussion about this question here: [The closure of $\{ z:|f(z)|<c\}$ is the set $\{z:|f(z)|\leq c\}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1744138/the-closure-of-zfzc-is-the-set-zfz-leq-c)

But there's only some indication about using the open map theorem. I'm familiarizated with it and I've tried to apply it on this question but I can't find the way it goes. I would really appreciate if someone could give me the manner of doing it. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to show that $\{z : |f(z)| \leq c\} \subseteq \overline{\{z : |f(z)| < c\}}$ (where $\overline{S}$ denotes closure of $S$). Clearly, we only need to worry about the set $\{z : |f(z)|= c\}$. So let $z$ s.t. $|f(z)| = c$. We need to show that $z$ is a limit point of $\{z : |f(z)| < c\}$. Let $U$ an open set containing $z$. We need to show that $U \cap \{z : |f(z)| < c\} \neq \emptyset$. But by the open mapping theorem $f(U)$ is an open set containing $f(z) = c$. Convince yourself that $\overline{\{w : |w| < c\}} = \{w : |w| \leq c\}$. Then since $f(U)$ is an open set containing $c$, $f(U) \cap \{w : |w| < c\} \neq \emptyset$. I.e. there is some $a \in U$ s.t. $|f(a)| < c$. Then $a \in U \cap \{z : |f(z)| < c\}$, so $U \cap \{z : |f(z)| < c\} \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: Wow! This was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just one comment, nearly at the end, you've written |f(U)|<c and I figure you wanted to say |f(a)|<c. Am I right?

Comment: Correct, I'll edit. Thanks!